# After a recent update to 10.14.4 trackpad stopped working on a Macbook Pro 2017

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, trackpad

Today I was prompted by the Mojave OS that I need to install an update, so I did. After the update was installed and I logged in I immediately noticed that trackpad does not work at all

As apple support suggested through their chat I've done the following without any success:
1. Restarted my macbook
2. Attempted to reset SMC by holding Shift+Control+Option+Power button.
3. Attempted to reset NVRAM by holding Command+Option+P+R. While holding these keys my macbook would turn on the screen for a couple of seconds (just a black screen, no logo) and then it would turn off entirely for about 10 seconds, then again lit-up black screen for a couple of seconds and so on. So I suspect I was never able to actually reset NVRAM successfully
4. Launched my macbook in the safe mode by holding Shift and then restarted it in regular mode.
5. Launched diagnostics mode by holding "D". It said that all hardware is fine.
6. Launched recovery mode by holding Command+R and then performed an HDD check. It didn't find anything that needed fixing.
7. Then again in recovery mode I reinstalled Mac OS. This did not help with the dead trackpad either.

So at this point I guess the only thing I wasn't able to do is to reset NVRAM properly and maybe there are other options to reset it other than to hold Command+Option+P+R. Or maybe there's some boot log somewhere that would indicate what went wrong while I was holding these keys and macbook failed to boot.

The next step I am considering is to factory reset this macbook. Will this help somehow or is it essentially the same as reinstalling Mac OS from recovery mode that I already did (without disk erraising).

I guess the last option is to consider that it is a hardware problem but if it is the case it seems kinda odd that trackpad stopped working right after I've installed the update.

Answer (score 1):

I’m currently faced with this problem. I’ve tried all the suggestions and one that seemed to fix it for a week or so was turning the unit off and holding CMD + q and then turning the unit on whilst holding it until you get to the login screen.

Comment: CMD+Q without any other modifiers? That seems strange as that is just "Quit". As far as I know CMD+Q on reboot doesn't nothing.